# KQL - Make the datasource variable

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i have 2 datasources which i want to be variable based on condition. But i cannot call them using variables. im not sure how can i make this work

```
let T1 = TableMetric;
let T2 = TableImperial;
let T3 = othertable;
let tablemetrics = case(@uommetrics=="meter",T1,@uommetrics=="imperial",T2,T3);
tablemetrics
```

> Semantic error: '' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named
> 'T1'. Query: 'let T1 = TableMetric; let T2 = TableImperial; let T3 =
> othertable; let tablemetrics =
> case('a'=="meter",T1,'a'=="imperial",T2,T3); tablemetrics

Comment: Posted an answer, but I must say that I'm getting https://xyproblem.info/ vibes from this

Answer (score 1):

This logic can be implemented with [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator

```
.set TableMetric <| datatable(i:int)[1,2,3]

.set TableImperial <| datatable(i:int)[4,5,6]

.set othertable <| datatable(i:int)[7,8,9]
```

---

```
let uommetrics = "xxx";
union 
    (TableMetric   | where uommetrics == "meter")
   ,(TableImperial | where uommetrics == "imperial")
   ,(othertable    | where uommetrics !in ("meter", "imperial"))
```

| i |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |